# How to authenticate Databrics API using .netrc file

Tags: databricks, .netrc

I have created ".netrc " file on my machine and trying below databricks rest api call. But it always giving an unauthorized error. How to create .netrc file in Databricks?

curl -n -X GET https:///api/2.0/token/list

How to use .netrc file with databricks api?

Answer (score 3):

My .netrc file looks like this:

```
machine northeurope.azuredatabricks.net
login token
password dapicxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Machine should be the region where your workspace is deployed, login is always token and the password the token created for your user.

See [Databricks documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/authentication.html#authentication) how to create the token.

Comment: Can't we log in using UserId and password?

Comment: You have to generate a token in the Databricks- UI. This is your Password. Login is always token. You don't use your userid/ pwd.

Comment: actually, my main purpose to generate .netrc file is to generate token automatically. I want to deploy Data Factory Databricks activity and for that I need User Token. Is there any other way to generate token?

Comment: You need an initial token to authenticate. Then you can also use the API for token management, see also https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/tokens.html .

Comment: You need an initial token to authenticate. Then you can also use the API for token management, see also https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/tokens.html .

Comment: Yes. the same thing I am trying. But to create the token I have to pass token in the authorization header. So I am trying to use curl command for this. I read here that using .netrc file we can authenticate API request. https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/authentication.html.

Comment: Yes, but the first token has to be created in the UI, unfortuanetly the first token can not be created via the REST API.

Comment: Is it possible using Databricks CLI?

Comment: What about more than 1 token? What is the format in .netrc file?

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to configure databricks cli is to install databricks-cli package using the below command

```py
pip install --upgrade databricks-cli
```

Then:

```py
databricks configure --token (enter hostname/auth-token at prompt)
```

Instructions are available at https://pypi.org/project/databricks-cli/