# Databricks Azure - How to to run API commands from a Notebook

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

How to run within Databricks notebook - API for checking other running jobs:

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `%%sh` [cell magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-sh) and then use the usual `curl` commands, e.g.:

```
%%sh
curl -n -X GET https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/jobs/list
```

(You'll need to [authenticate first though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication): The `-n` flag is for an [.netrc](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-netrc) file. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720970/how-to-authenticate-databrics-api-using-netrc-file) might be useful for that.)

I think this is the only option: Jobs can be managed either through the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs) or through the [Databricks GUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/jobs). I can't see anything about managing jobs using [`dbutils`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils), for instance.